# sencha listview is not clickabale

Tags: listview, sencha-touch-2, onclicklistener

I have a listview in sencha which shows the records from web sql database. I'm loading my store in launch function of app.js so that my listview can show the records. But listview is not clickable.Anyhow if i don't load store like this and after entering data in web sql through a view & then load store then the listview is clickable.I haven't seen any person facing this problem. I don't why this is happening help me out if i'm making any mistake here:

```
//launch function of app.js
launch: function() {                           
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    if(Ext.getStore('Events') != null)
    {
        Ext.getStore('Events').load();
    }
    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('FirstApp.view.Main'));

}

//my store
Ext.define('FirstApp.store.Events',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model:  'FirstApp.model.Event',
    storeId:    'Events'
    }

});

//view class of listview
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.Events',{
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype:  'eventList',
id: 'eventList',

requires:[  'Ext.data.Store','FirstApp.store.Events'],
config: {
    title:  'Events',
    iconCls:    'organize',
    store:  'Events',
    itemTpl:    '{name}',
    onItemDisclosure:   true
},

initialize:function(){

    /*if(Ext.getStore('Events') != null)
    {
        Ext.getStore('Events').load();
    }*/
}

});

//my model class
Ext.define("FirstApp.model.Event", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
      fields: [
         {name: "event_Id", type:   "INTEGER"},
         "name",
         "description",
         {name: "pic_url",  type:   "text", defaultValue:   ""},
         {name: "modified_Date",    type: "date",   defaultValue: new Date()},
         {name: "created_Date", type: "date",   defaultValue: new Date()},
      ],
      proxy: {
        type: "sql"
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your full code? For what I can see I can say make some considerations:
 - you are loading your store twice, in your view initialization and inside launch function
 - you can use `autoLoad : true` inside store config for automatic loading
 - I don't see any defined proxy in your store neither inline data, take a look on [sencha store docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

Comment: :Thanks for replying thats my fault i'm just loading my store in launch function of app.js. initialize function of view is commented i have updated code above.But its nt running in both cases.And proxy is defined in model class so no need to define in store too, i think